# How to split a large package without breaking client code?

Tags: go

Let's say I have a library package called **foobar**.

Over time it became big and heavy.

Fortunately it's separable, I managed to split its functionality into two separate packages **foo** and **bar** -- most clients will only need to use one or the other.

Since my library is already in use by many clients, for compatibility I still want to maintain a **foobar** package as a proxy to the current functionality found in both **foo** and **bar**.

How does one achieve this in Go ?

One way that comes to mind is to create aliases in **foobar** for each struct/function in **foo** and **bar**. So if **foo** defines `F()` and **bar** defines `B()`, I would have in **foobar**:

```
var (
  F = foo.F
  B = bar.B
)
```

But I am hoping for an easier/cleaner way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating an alias package is the only way.
But your attempt probably won't work: It works only for functions and variables and consts but not for types. For types you have to duplicate the type in foobar.

I wouldn't do this. Just have foobar around in version 1 and start anew with foo and bar (maybe directly in version 2).

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that. It is unfortunate, as this is a natural phenomena as software grows, and coming out with a new version (breaking the API) is too costly a solution in many cases, including mine.

Comment: wouldn't `type MyType foo.MyType` and `type OtherType bar.OtherType` mostly work? Although I can see that interfering badly with methods. Hm.

Comment: @Vatine Yes: all methods are lost. Additionally: type switches and type asserts would fail and reflection might break. So: No, this doesn't "mostly work".

Comment: So just even function assignment probably won't work, in a lot of cases. Although very thing shims MIGHT work.